# React Website applying different css after npm run build

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, netlify

I am creating a production build of my website with `npm run build` and using netlify to host it. After creating the production build the look of the website has changed dramatically and I can't understand why.

Before
[image: Development] [View on codesandbox](https://y003q.csb.app/about)

 After

[Production](https://spokanepowerstroke.net/)

Several other aspects are different too on almost every page.
I've had this issue before when I found that there were multiple parts of my Css that were changing the same Html tag, but I have not seen that in this code.

[github repo](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/spokane-power-stroke)
Any advice you have will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my mistake.
Don't mix bootstrap, react-bootstrap, and custom css into a frankenstien's monster like I did. There's a reason for my SOF name. 
If anyone else has this problem in the future, simplify your css, and you might have to redo the whole layout.